# Using the cut and dplyr::mutate with a user defined function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, cut

I am a relatively new user to R (coming from Stata) and was looking to create a user defined function in R that simulates Stata's egen cut command.

I've now succeeded--but I'm really unsure why--and was hoping someone could explain what's going on.

```
#Create test dataframe and cut off points
test<-data.frame(x=c(0:10), y=c(0.1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6))
cuts<-list(0,1,2,3,4,100)

#trial non function version: works
test %>% mutate(v_group = cut(y, breaks = cuts, labels=FALSE)) %>% count(v_group) %>% mutate(freq=percent(n/sum(n)))


#set function
egen_cut<-function(df,v,points){
   stopifnot(is.character(v))

   df %>% mutate_(v= ~cut(v, breaks=points, labels=FALSE)) %>% count(v)

}


#trial function version: fails 
egen_cut(test,"y", points=cuts)


#try alternative function
egen_cut2 <- function(df,v, points) {

  stopifnot(is.character(v))

  df %>% mutate_(v_group = v) %>% mutate_(v_group = ~cut(v_group, breaks=points, labels=FALSE)) %>% count(v_group) %>% mutate(freq=percent(n/sum(n)))

}


#trial function version: works
egen_cut2(test,"y", points=cuts)
```

You can see that in my first attempt I get the error "x is not numeric", and in the second attempt it works.

I've done some reading and I think it has something to do with interp() and how this is used in dplyr:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

This has led me to think the better way of accomplishing my goal is with a function like this:

```
egen_cut <- function(df,v) {
  stopifnot(is.character(v))
  tmp <- interp(~cut(var, breaks =0:5, labels=FALSE), var=as.name(v))
  df %>% mutate_(v_group = tmp)
}
```

Which also works, but again, I don't think I fully understand the logic. Would really appreciate the help! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry eddi, copying error--now corrected. But main question still stands as to why interp is important.

Comment: This is what you're doing in your function - `test %>% mutate_(v = ~cut("y", 1:11))`. Should be fairly clear why it fails. I'm not a `dplyr` user to suggest particular solutions - in `data.table` I'd use `get` and not mess with this NSE nonsense, but I can't make that work in `dplyr`.